# Add "weight" to Chip in ChipGroup to fill parent width

Tags: android, android-chips

I have 2 `Chip` inside a `ChipGroup`. I need them to fill the entire width of the screen, something like how we can do using `android:layout_weight` in a `LinearLayout`.

I have tried this:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    >

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/pill_button_height"
            android:id="@+id/chip1"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Chip.LeftRounded"
            android:text="Left"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/pill_button_height"
            android:id="@+id/chip2"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Chip.RightRounded"
            android:text="Right"
            />

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

But the `layout_weight` does not work and the chips simply vanish because the width is `0dp`.
If anyone knows how to solve this, without completely discarding `ChipGroup` and creating my own implementation, it would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: A `ChipGroup` doesn't inherit from any other view groups, so it seems like this isn't possible without a custom implementation or calculating widths programmatically.

Comment: Yeah, I am also inclined to believe that it is not possible. *Sigh*

Comment: It might be easier to do away with the `ChipGroup` altogether and just handle the checking yourself.

Comment: I am doing exactly that. Using `Chip` but not not `ChipGroup`.